# NGINX + Tomcat as reverse proxy configuration error

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have read a lot in stackoverflow about my problem, but I couldn't find out the solution.

I need to set a reverse proxy using NGINX with my Tomcat server, so when I access to `my-page.com` the request would be attended by NGINX and redirected to `my-page.com:8080/myApp`, where Tomcat server is listening.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-page.com` content is:

```
server {
    server_name my-page.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080/myApp;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

And I have set the `Connector` directive in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` file like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           proxyName="my-page.com"
           proxyPort="80" />
```

When I go to `my-page.com`, the browser always drive me to the main page of NGINX, but never to Tomcat server main page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-page.com` symlinked in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` ?

Comment: I have executed: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-page.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`